# Как вытащить значение из Axios + (TRY - CATCH) + async await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, promise, cheerio

Есть такой код:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


const parseBilanzGuv = async (param) => {
      
  let link = 'https://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?_search=' + param;
      
  try{
    await axios.get(link)
          
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(res => {
            
        let html = res;
        $ = cheerio.load( html, { decodeEntities: false } );
            

        return {symbol: 'значение'};
            
      })
          
        
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
      
  catch(e){
    console.log("err- ", e);
  }
      
};
    
    
parseBilanzGuv('US30161N1019').then(function(result) {
   console.log(result); // undefined
});
```

При попытке получить возвращаемое значение из функции `parseBilanzGuv()` - получаю `undefined`.

Вопрос:
Что необходимо изменить в коде, что бы вытащить значение `symbol: 'значение';` стало возможным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, вы ведь ничего не возвращаете из функции `parseBilanzGuv()`. Поставьте `return` вместо `await` перед `axios.get(link)`, чтобы вернуть результирующий Promise.

Хотя ещё лучше, наверное, не смешивать цепочки промисов и async/await, то есть заменить цепочку на ряд await и вернуть уже `{symbol: 'значение'}`, так будет последовательнее.

```js
const parseBilanzGuv = async (param) => {
  let link = 'https://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?_search=' + param;
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(link);
    const html = await res.data;
    $ = cheerio.load(html, { decodeEntities: false });
    return { symbol: 'значение' };
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('err- ', e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Первый вариант сработал - второй выдает синтаксическую ошибку какую то.
http://joxi.ru/EA4dWyzHpOGXJA

Comment: Видимо, он встроился в код неудачно. Может, во время редактирования вложенность блоков перепуталась. Ну, если первый работает, можно не мучиться)